# Variables from a specific class equality both sides still changing together if one of the sides change

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and WPF, and I am trying to define a new variable from a class and to give this new variable a value from an old variable and then make some changes to the new one. But the problem is that the new variable is still connected to the old variable and if I change anything in the new one, the changes will effect the old one:

```
MW.CurrentPreviewJob = addjob;
```

MW is another page than the page I am writing the code in,

and I define them as follows:

```
public static Job addjob;

public Job CurrentPreviewJob
{
    get { return _currentPreviewJob; }
    set { 
        _currentPreviewJob = value; 
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPreviewJob"); 
    }
}
```

the class for the two variables is same and it is:

```
 public partial class Job
 {
     public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
     public string JOB_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
     public byte[] TARGET_IMAGE { get; set; }
     public int JOB_USER { get; set; }
 }
```

So how can I take the value of `CurrentPreviewJob` without stay connecting to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because an object of a class is a reference type.
Let's take a look at an example:
We create an object of your class:

```
Job someJob = new Job();
```

What exactly is someJob? Well, when you create an instance of an object it is held in special area of memory, and `someJob` holds a **reference** to it (which is an address under which the program can find the instance in the memory).
So when you do something like:

```
Job someOtherJob = someJob;
```

you actually tell `someOtherJob` object to hold reference to the same address in a memmory as `someJob` object. that's how reference types work.

Now, if you do, for example:

```
someOtherJob.JOB_DESCRIPTION = "I changed that description in some other job object";
```

This is what happens: program checks the address which is referenced by `somOtherJob` object, goes there, finds the instance, and change its `JOB_DESCRIPTION` property's value. **BUT** remember that `someJob` objct (the "old" one) has a reference to the same instance in the memory - hnce, it will have the same, changed JOB_DESCRIPTION.

The most elegant thing to do here is to implement some kind of cloning method on the Job class.

```
public partial class Job
    {
        public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
        public string JOB_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public byte[] TARGET_IMAGE { get; set; }
        public int JOB_USER { get; set; }
        public Job Clone() {
        Job clone = new Job();
        clone.JOB_ID = this.JOB_ID;
        clone.JOB_DESCRIPTION = this.JOB_DESCRIPTION;
        clone.TARGET_IMAGE = this.TARGET_IMAGE;
        clone.JOB_USER = this.JOB_USER;
        return clone;
        }
    }
```

and use it like:
Job someOtherJob = someJob.Clone();

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it is clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

That happens because both `CurrentPreviewJob` and `addjob` are [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx). They both reference the same object in the memory. So whatever you do to one variable will also affect the other, since they are pointing to the same object. You can make your `Job` have a `Clone` method like this:

```
public partial class Job
{
    public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
    public string JOB_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public byte[] TARGET_IMAGE { get; set; }
    public int JOB_USER { get; set; }

    public Job Clone()
    {
        return new Job {
            JOB_ID = this.JOB_ID,
            JOB_DESCRIPTION = this.JOB_DESCRIPTION,
            TARGET_IMAGE = this.TARGET_IMAGE,
            JOB_USER = this.JOB_USER
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can assign your `CurrentPreviewJob` like this:

```
MW.CurrentPreviewJob = addjob.Clone();
```

This will make another object so your second variable is no longer linked to your previous.
Or another way is to make your class a [struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx)

Comment: I was getting ready to up-vote, then saw you mention `struct`... not really a good option in most cases.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but its his choice. He can research about it and choose what is the best for his situation. But they aren't always bad. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class

Comment: The problem is that it could have wider implicatations, since we don't know what else this is used for (note the `partial` in the definition). `struct` does have its uses, but I feel it should be very limited and generally not something a beginner should be messing with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because Job is a class, and classes are reference types, meaning that if you assign one job variable to another, you just have too variables referencing the same data.

You could declare Job as a struct, which are value types and assignment would automatically create a copy.

I tend to avoid structs, simply because I don't like having to copy things around just to change properties, so I'd suggest adding an appropriate constructor to Job, like:

```
public Job(Job other) {
    this.JOB_ID = other.JOB_ID;
    this.JOB_DESCRIPTION = other.JOB_DESCRIPTION;
    //...same for the other fields
}
```

Once you have the constructor, you can clone the object by doing:

```
var NewJob = new Job(OldJob);
```